# jQuery $.ajax execution slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having difficulty on some websites I work on with slow executing jQuery `$.ajax`.

I am **not** talking about the server taking a long time to respond. I am talking about the actual execution of the `$.ajax` function taking a long time.

**Normal (fast) example**

Going to [jQuery.org](https://jquery.org/) and running the following code takes **3ms**:

```
var start = (new Date()).getTime();
$.get("https://jquery.org/projects/")
var end = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("executed in " + (end - start) + "ms")
```

**Bad (slow) example**

However, running very similar code on a [demo website](http://sauce-demo.myshopify.com/) I'm working on takes **324ms**:

```
var start = (new Date()).getTime();
$.get("http://sauce-demo.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/bronze-sandals")
var end = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log("executed in " + (end - start) + "ms")
```

---

Now obviously the response from `$.ajax` (and therefore `$.get`) is going to be async. But what could be causing such a huge increase in execution time?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you aren't setting the secong one as sync, using maybe ajax global setup???

Comment: Takes only 2ms here: http://jsfiddle.net/2L7g7be3/

Comment: I tried in jsfiddle and both of those ran in 1ms for me.

Comment: @A.Wolff make an excellent suggestion, indeed I could say that you must take a bps (size/time), not ms difference because you are not getting the same data.

Comment: Definitely looks like it's not async. Add an alert after the get and you'll see there's a delay. Try the scripts in [here]( http://jsfiddle.net/2L7g7be3/2/) and you'll see there's a difference. The network tab also has a timing tab where you can see that they all take mostly 300ms but ones is async and one is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the awesome comments guys. You're absolutely right - it looks like there was a global `async: false` set up nested in one of the JavaScript files:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});
```

I wasn't aware jQuery had a global async setup.

Comment: yup - this did it for me... thank you!